# Passing Checkbox values to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am making a model where users can belong to multiple teams and teams have multiple people.
I have checkboxes but they don't pass the value onto the object.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  has_many :teams 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams
end


class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

Here is the code in my controller

```
def create
@users = User.all
@user = User.new
@teams = Team.all
@user.attributes = {:teams => []}.merge(params[:user] || {})
end
```

Here is the code in my view file

```
<%= form_for @user, url: {action: "create"}  do |f| %>
<%= f.label :teams%>
<% for team in @teams %>
<%= check_box_tag team.name, team.name, false, :teams => team.name%>      
<%=  team.name -%>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag "Create User" %>
```

I am trying to show it into

```
<%= user.teams.name %>
```

But the only output is "Team"
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you reporting two problems (passing checkbox values and displaying team name)? `user.teams` refers to the whole collection of teams the user might belong to. So `name` isn't the name of a team, but might be picking up the `name` method of the class (which is `Team`). You need to show a specific team by selecting a team from `user.teams` (e.g., `first_team = user.teams.first`) then show its name (e.g., `first_team.name`).

Comment: @mbratch I didnt know checkbox sends a boolean. How can I get it to send the team name?  team.name calls the team names. each team can have many names.

Comment: Sorry, I'm mistaken (got a little confused). You can use it to send a name, which is the value of the checkbox element. Did you try to do a view source (HTML) from your browser? See what that looks like. It can give a clue as to what's happening.

Comment: First, teams is ActiveRecord::Relation class, so you cannot call .name on it. Second, check_box_tag is currently not associated with the @user, so try using fields_for in the form.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can't do a many-to-many relationship that way... you need to do `has_many :through` or alternatively  `has_and_belongs_to_many` Nice explanation here...

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html